# How can I specify which branch should be checked out in a fresh clone?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-extensions

In Git Extensions, the user can, when cloning a repository, specify which branch (possibly other than `master`) should be checked out in the resulting clone.

How can I do that at the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, as often, is in the man pages (in the `git-clone` man page, here):

```
--branch <name>, -b <name>

    Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed
    to by the cloned repository's HEAD, point to <name> branch
    instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will
    be checked out.  --branch can also take tags and detaches the
    HEAD at that commit in the resulting repository.
```

So you want to run

```
git clone --branch <name> <repository>
```

where `<name>` stands for the name of the branch that you want checked out in your clone of `<repository>`.

---

#### Example

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ git clone --branch maint https://github.com/git/git
$ cd git
$ git branch
* maint
```

Comment: @dennis, note that the text cited from the `git clone` manual page hints that if you want everyone cloning get a branch other than "master" be checked out by default, make the `HEAD` ref in the main repo point to that branch, not "master".

Comment: How to "make the HEAD ref in the main repo point to that branch"?

Comment: @KcFnMi If you mean "in the remote repo", you have to do it in that repo; you cannot do it from a clone. VonC has a good answer about this somewhere (I'll try to find it). In the GitHub web interface, you need to click "branch" and then "change default branch".