# Why I need additional step when cloning if branch name is 'main'

Tags: git, git-clone

In the past, when the default branch is 'master' when creating a repository, cloning will auto pull/fetch the files in the branch.

However after I change git global init.defaultBranch to 'main', cloning require additional steps to actually get the file:

```sh
git fetch
git pull origin main
```

If I want to push to the repo, the first time I have to do the following:

```sh
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

Those steps are not required when I was using 'master'. How can I make it automatic again?

PS: I am using gitea as git repo server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default branch that is checked out when cloning is determined by the remote repo. But you can [change it when cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26238572/184546) too.

To [change your default branch in gitea](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/config-cheat-sheet/) set the DEFAULT_BRANCH parameter.